# Find multiple haystacks between the same needle

Tags: vb.net, string

I am currently trying to develop an application that obtains data from a certain webpage.

Lets say this webpage has the following content:

```
<needle1>HAYSTACK 1<needle2>
<needle1>HAYSTACK 2<needle2>
<needle1>HAYSTACK 3<needle2>
<needle1>HAYSTACK 4<needle2>
<needle1>HAYSTACK 5<needle2>
```

And I have the following VB.NET code:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim FullPage As String = webClient.DownloadString("PAGE URL HERE")
Dim ExtractedInfo As String = GetBetween(FullPage, "<needle1>", "<needle2>")
```

GetBetween is the following function:

```
Function GetBetween(ByVal haystack As String, ByVal needle As String, ByVal needle_two As String) As String
    Dim istart As Integer = InStr(haystack, needle)
    If istart > 0 Then
        Dim istop As Integer = InStr(istart, haystack, needle_two)
        If istop > 0 Then
            Dim value As String = haystack.Substring(istart + Len(needle) - 1, istop - istart - Len(needle))
            Return value
        End If
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

By using the code mentioned, ExtractedInfo is always equal to "HAYSTACK 1" because it always gets the haystack from the first occurrence it finds.

My question is: How to setup ExtractedInfo like some kind of array in order for it to look for the second, third, fourth, etc... occurrences.

Something like:

```
ExtractedInfo(1) = HAYSTACK 1
ExtractedInfo(2) = HAYSTACK 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  I think this is what you were actually asking.  You would call the GetBetween function one time for each set of "needles".

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim FullPage As String = webClient.DownloadString("PAGE URL HERE")
Dim ExtractedInfo As List (Of String) = GetBetween(FullPage, "<needle1>", "<needle2>")

Function GetBetween(ByVal haystack As String, ByVal needle As String, ByVal needle2 As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim result As New List(Of String)
        Dim split1 As String() = Split(haystack, needle).ToArray
        For Each item In split1
            Dim split2 As String() = Split(item, needle2)
            Dim include As Boolean = True
            For Each element In split2
                If include Then
                    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element) = False Then result.Add(element)
                End If
                include = Not include
            Next element
        Next item

        Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer.
I have altered the code like you indicated but it seems that when I call the function, I get this error:

Error 1 Argument not specified for parameter 'ExtractedInfo' of 'Public Function GetBetween(haystack As String, needle As String, needle_two As String, ByRef ExtractedInfo As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't passing it the ExtractedInfo list as the last parameter.  But check my edited answer; I think that is what you are really looking for.